# Java ошибка в каком-то модуле Tika

Tags: java, apache, maven

Пишу приложение на java для обработки файлов, для этого использую библиотеку apache Tika.

При запуске из консоли появляется такое сообщение:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b0/.m2/repository/org/apache/tika/tika-app/1.25/tika-app-1.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b0/.m2/repository/org/apache/tika/tika-app/1.2/tika-app-1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b0/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.9/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
фев 03, 2021 3:26:48 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.

фев 03, 2021 3:26:48 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
```

Вот мой pom.xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.vit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jpa-utility</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring JPA</name>

    <properties>
        <tika>1.2</tika>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tika-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>     
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-debugger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ome</groupId>
            <artifactId>bio-formats</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Helper's dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gagravarr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-tika</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
               
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                       <mainClass>com.vit.TikaSample</mainClass>
                       
                       <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                   <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                      
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.vit.TikaSample</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
                    
        </plugins>
    
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Читал об этом, подключал разные модули, о которых было написано, но результат был такой же как и без этих плагинов.
А также подключал плагин sqlite-jdbc из репозитория maven: https://mvnrepository.com/

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? У кого есть какие мысли, заранее спасибо.

Comment: В приведенном логе много сообщений. О каком конкретно из (т.е. о какой проблеме) вы спрашиваете?

Comment: В сообщении есть Warning, что так или иначе не должно быть при нормальном поведении программы. Речь идет о: 
WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.

WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.